# Video frames with timestamp or export frame name and timestamp to excel file

Tags: powershell, ffmpeg, video-processing

I need to break a video into frames (60fps) and frame name must be in the fashion of %d_hh-mm-ss.ms.png, Or, any solution that gives frame name, and the time in excel file will work

Note: - time here must be the time at which the frame appeared in the video

Comment: Just make ffmpeg to output `%d.png`, and generate their timestamps in Excel by creating Column A to be integers counting up from 0 to the number in the last PNG file, then populate the time cells with the equation `=A1/60/86400` (need to customize the format so it'll show milliseconds). Both of these tricks are easily found via internet search.

Comment: Okay, cool. You've told us what you are trying to do. What's your question? Which parts of this do you already know how to do? You've tagged this with [tag:ffmpeg], so I guess you've identified a tool you can use.